# Mask a dynamic URL

Tags: path-aliases

Is there a way to mask a dynamic url in Drupal?

**Original URL:**
site.com/user/%/orders

**Masked URL:**
site.com/orders

Comment: instead of a dynamic url, you could create a custom module that creates a custom tab on user page. In that custom user tab, you display your order view. You should still be able to use "get nid from url" in views.

Comment: Do you want to use site.com/orders? That would work for just a user account. You cannot mask the user ID, and make it work for all the user accounts. Or do you want to use site.com/orders/%uid?

Comment: We have a number of sections under the user account which are being served via views, these include a section for orders, dashboard etc. To simplify things on the user side I would like the user to be able to just access orders or dashboard directly via a url, and for it to display as /orders or /dashboard rather than needing the user id. Come to think of it, I might attempt creating the view with a fixed url and using the logged in user as contextual filter rather than an argument. I'm going to attempt the "Page Manager" option though, and see if that works for our case.

Answer (score 1):

Install **Page Manager** module. It is bundled with [CTools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools) which is a requirement for [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), so chances are it is on your system already.

Go to Structure->Pages->Add custom page:

- **Administrative title:** Masked Orders
- **Path:** orders
- **Variant Type:** HTTP response Code
- **Optional features:** Access control, Contexts
- Click Continue

**Next page is:** Basic settings » Access control » Contexts » Panel settings

- Select `Context exists`, click Add button. In modal select context:
  `Logged in User Exists` and click Save
- Click Continue

**Next page is:** Basic settings » Access control » Contexts » Panel settings

- Select `User` and click Add Context button. On modal **tick** `Logged in user`
  and click Finish.
- Click Continue

**Next page is:** Basic settings » Access control » Contexts » Panel settings

- Change Administrative title machine name to: http_response_code
- Select Response Code: 301 Redirect
- Add Redirect destination: `user/%user:uid/orders`
- Click Finish

On next page click: Update and save

Test the path `orders`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do masking you'd need to use .htaccess rules, which allows you do to that URL masking.

See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928498/htaccess-url-masking-instead-of-redirecting

On your case it could look something like this:

```
# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /orders/
  RewriteRule .* user/%1/orders [NC]
```

For your use case however you don't specify if your users are authenticated, hence seen their own orders, or if you want to mask the url for anonymous users (for which this example could be your path to follow)